# Magento 2: how to insert data when submit product in backend?

Tags: magento2, product-attribute

I am a newbie for magento 2 and try to save data into custom table when user submit a product data in backend.

I tried to use `di.xml` and `events.xml`, but I still don't know when and where do this action insert the data into table.

Because there is basic on the exist page that is product submit page, not a new page to do it.

So, I am confused the data flow.

Updated:

I used the events.xml to do it. but not working for me.
there is the file code:

Demo\User\etc\adminhtml\events.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2015 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="controller_action_catalog_product_save_entity_after'">
        <observer name="demo_user_product" instance="Demo\User\Model\Product" method="testEvent" />
    </event>
</config>
```

Demo\User\Model\Product:

```
<?php
namespace Demo\User\Model;
use Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel as AbstractModel;
class Product extends AbstractModel
{
    public function testEvent()
    {
        $myfile = fopen("/file_path/Product.txt", "w");
        fwrite($myfile, 1);
        fclose($myfile);
    }
}
```

when I click the save button of product in backend, there is no data is written into "Product.txt" file. this file's permission is 777.
so, anybody know what's wrong in my code?

Comment: anybody know how to solve my question? need your help.

Comment: I used the events.xml to do it. but not working for me.

Comment: which Magento version? 

`method` attribute is not valid (check magento/framework/Event/etc/events.xsd:48)

An observer must implements `\Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface`, so you need to define `execute` method

Comment: @Brice version is 2.0.2. i changed the function name to execute, but it don'ts still work.

Comment: there is also a typo in your XML `<event name="controller_action_catalog_product_save_entity_after">` (a quote)

Comment: @Brice thanks for your help. i modified this typo. but got a error msg:
Class Demo\User\Model\Product does not exist
after click save of product button. 
i checked Product file is in the Model folder and the Product class is defined. So, what's wrong now?

Comment: @Brice Thanks for your help. i made a mistake about the class name. it works for me now.

Answer (score 3):

You can use events for this. But I recommend using the event `catalog_product_save_after` instead of `controller_action_catalog_product_save_entity_after`.

Here is what you need. Let's say your module name is `Demo_User`.

`app/code/Demo/User/registration.php` - the registration file

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Demo_User',
    __DIR__
);
```

`app/code/Demo/User/etc/module.xml` - the module declaration file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Demo_User" setup_version="2.0.0">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Catalog"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

`app/code/Demo/User/etc/adminhtml/events.xml` - the event declaration file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="catalog_product_save_after">
        <observer name="some_unique_name_here" instance="Demo\User\Observer\Adminhtml\Product" />
    </event>
</config>
```

`app/code/Demo/User/Observer/Adminhtml/Product.php` - the actual observer.

```
<?php 
namespace Demo\User\Observer\Adminhtml;

use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class Product implements ObserverInterface
{
    public function __execute(Observer $observer)
    {
         //your code here
         //you can access the product being saved like this
         $product = $observer->getEvent()->getProduct();
    }
}
```

run in the console `php bin/magento setup:upgrade` and you should be good to go.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have modified my code according @Brice to solve my question.
 I will check your advice whether works for me or not

Comment: I your code is working, too. but i can get the product data with "$observer->getEvent()->getProduct();". once i used this code, i will get a blank page after refresh the product editing page. so, what's wrong?

Comment: Add ->getData after to get only the product data

Comment: I know this is Old thread. But will this Event work for Product Bulk Import as well ??

Comment: @JItendraRana. No it doesn't. It works only for when you specifically call the save method from the product model.

Comment: So which Event should i use for Bulk Import ?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know.