# Magento 2.4 - Observer For Catalog Product Save After Not Working

Tags: event-observer, magento2.4

I have referenced a few different questions here and other articles online, but cannot for the life of me determine what is going wrong.

Referenced:

- [Event not triggered when new product added in admin : Magento 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/241814/event-not-triggered-when-new-product-added-in-admin-magento-2)
- https://magecomp.com/blog/perform-operation-product-magento-2/
- [Magento 2: how to insert data when submit product in backend?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/105357/magento-2-how-to-insert-data-when-submit-product-in-backend)

**Context:**
Website is a multi-vendor marketplace. I'm looking to save a timestamp at the moment a new product is added to the catalog by a vendor.

**Desired result:**
Upon a new product being created, the Observer will insert the datetime to a custom database table.

I understand this datetime is already stored in `catalog_product_entity`, but I need it saved in a separate table, as the datetime will be changed periodically for each product. The `$vendorId` portion can be ignored, which is why I'm simply using a static integer for that column until I'm able to get this working at all. Please also excuse the rudimentary method of saving said data to the table. Again, I know for a fact that method works elsewhere, which is why I'm using it here. To ensure that it's not the issue, but something else wider in scope.

**Actual Result**: Data is not inserted into the custom database table.

**Files**
`Namespace\Custom\etc\module.xml`

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
      <module name="Namespace_Custom" setup_version="0.0.1">
        <sequence>
             <module name="Magento_Catalog"/>
         </sequence>
      </module>
    </config>
```

`Namespace\Custom\registration.php`

```
<?php

\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE, 'Namespace_Custom',
    __DIR__
);
```

`Namespace\Custom\etc\adminhtml\events.xml`

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="catalog_product_new_action">
        <observer name="Namespace_Custom_Product_Save_After" instance="Namespace\Custom\Observer\Adminhtml\ProductSaveAfter" />
    </event>
</config>
```

`Namespace\Custom\Observer\Adminhtml\ProductSaveAfter.php`

```
    <?php

    namespace Namespace\Custom\Observer\Adminhtml;

    use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
    use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

    class ProductSaveAfter implements ObserverInterface
    {
      /**
       * @var ObjectManagerInterface
      */
       protected $_objectManager;

      /**
      * @param \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $objectManager
      */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $objectManager
    ) {
        $this->_objectManager = $objectManager;
    }

    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
     
        $product = $observer->getEvent()->getProduct();
        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();

        if($product->isObjectNew()){
          $productId = $product->getId();        


          $resource = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection');
          $connection = $resource->getConnection();
          $table = $resource->getTableName('catalog_product_custom');

          $query = "INSERT INTO " . $table . " (entity_id, vendor_id, date_time)
          VALUES ($productId, 99, UNIX_TIMESTAMP())";
          $connection->query($query);
        }

    }
}
```

I have also tried using `catalog_product_edit_action` event.

Comment: Could you check if your observer code fired or not? Or your observer code fired but not save the data into the database?

Comment: @TuVan Using the profiler, I see the `catalog_product_edit_action` fired both on the vendor's side and in the admin panel, but no sign of my Observer (I did check this prior to changing to `new_action`). I'm not actually seeing `catalog_product_new_action` event being fired on either vendor or admin side.

Comment: Yep, both events are not fit your need. `catalog_product_new_action` call when you  go to "Create a new product" page, `catalog_product_edit_action` call when you go to "Edit a product" page. I'll write the answer to help you resolve your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `controller_action_catalog_product_save_entity_after` event for product save after.

Change your events.xml to:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="controller_action_catalog_product_save_entity_after">
        <observer name="Namespace_Custom_Product_Save_After" instance="Namespace\Custom\Observer\Adminhtml\ProductSaveAfter" />
    </event>
</config>
```

I've fixed some issues and improved your Observer class:

```
<?php

namespace Namespace\Custom\Observer\Adminhtml;

use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class ProductSaveAfter implements ObserverInterface
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection
     */
    protected $resource;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection $resource
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection $resource
    ) {
        $this->resource = $resource;
    }

    public function execute(Observer $observer)
    {
        $product = $observer->getEvent()->getProduct();

        if ($product->isObjectNew()) {
            $table = $this->resource->getTableName('catalog_product_custom');
            $now = new \DateTime();
            $createdAt = $now->format(\Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime::DATETIME_PHP_FORMAT);
            $vendorId = 99;
            $this->resource->getConnection()->insert(
                $table,
                ["entity_id" => $product->getId(), "vendor_id" => $vendorId, "date_time" => $createdAt]
            );
        }
    }
}
```

Remove `generated` folder and re compile code:

```
rm -rf generated
bin/magento setup:di:compile
```

You are done.

Comment: You're correct, that event is the one that's needed. Appreciate the better code for inserting the data as well.

Comment: Glad to help you. Cheers!